# Python Eve with custom webserver

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, eve

I would like to exploit Python Eve features, but I have a custom web environment where I have my Request objects and (can be disabled) a Router.

I know Python Eve is built on top of Flask and those features are already there, but I would like somehow to wrap/adapt my custom requests into Python Eve / Flask ones.

I have a process acting as a webserver (It receives and sends messages in protocols different from HTTP). I was searching for a standard way to interface it to Eve or Flask. I found out [WSGI](http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

---

To further clarify: Imagine you have your ESB which is able to vehicle HTTP requests.

If you want to handle those requests with Eve, you should build a gateway/bridge.

It means, implementing something that:

1. Receives the proprietary or not standard protocol containing the request
2. Extracts the most important parameters from the request, such as URL, QUERY_STRING, HTTP method and so on...
3. Fills a WSGI Environment with those parameters following the [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/)
4. Runs the WSGI application (in our case an Eve instance)
5. We get the response from the WSGI application
6. Pack the response back into your proprietary or custom protocol
7. Send back to requestor

A really simple example can be found at http://ivory.idyll.org/articles/wsgi-intro/what-is-wsgi.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean. Do you want to use Eve with a different (custom) framework other than Flask? That's going to be really hard without an almost total rewrite, as Eve is, in fact, a Flask application (a subclass actually).

Comment: Hi Nicola, I just managed to make it run using it as a wsgi. Luckly my env can run wsgi apps.